# R function to select value from two vectors, based on condition

Tags: r

I have three vectors, `v_1,v_2,b`. `b` consists of booleans. I would like to construct a new vector `v` that takes as its ith coordinate the value `v_1[[i]]` if `b[[i]]==TRUE`, and `v_2[[i]]` otherwise. Is there a vectorized function that does this?

Sorry if the question is too basic.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Function is `ifelse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
set.seed(123)
v_1 <- letters[1:5]
v_2 <-  1:5
b <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, replace = TRUE)

v <- ifelse(b, v_1, v_2)
v
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "4" "e"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>